# why 'float' object is not iterable

Tags: for-loop, sum, floating-accuracy

I am a beginner, so i try to practice as much as i can. In below code, i have to extract numbers from a text file with hundred lines and sum numbers. I wrote below code and the ouput message is : float object are not iterable.
I will appreciate help and advises.

```
fname = 'mbox-short.txt'
fh = open(fname,"r")

count = 0
for line in fh :
    line = line.rstrip()
    if not line.startswith('X-DSPAM-Confidence:') : continue
    count = count + 1
    #print(count)

    colonn_pos = line.find(':')
    fnum = line[colonn_pos+1:]
    numbers = float(fnum)
    #print(numbers)

total = 0
for values in numbers :
    if values < 1 :
        total = total + values
    print(total)
```

Here below numbers output to sum :

0.8475
0.6178
0.6961
0.7565
0.7626
0.7556
0.7002
0.7615
0.7601

Comment: Why would a float object be iterable? What would you expect from e.g. `for something in 1.0:`?

Answer (score 0):

You're setting `numbers` to a single float object, which is not iterable.

If you want to iterate over all of the floats that are generated by the first loop, you should create a list called "numbers" and `append()` every individual float to it.

```py
numbers = []
count = 0
for line in fh :
    line = line.rstrip()
    ...
    numbers.append(float(fnum))

total = 0
for value in numbers:
...
```

I would also point out that iterating over a list to generate a list that you iterate over again is redundant, so I'd actually change it to this:

```py
count = 0
total = 0.0
for line in fh :
    line = line.rstrip()
    ...
    num = float(fnum)
    if num < 1:
        total += num
    print(total)
```